# bash syntax error while running docker command

Tags: git, bash, docker, docker-machine

I was getting an error while running the docker ps command which is -

```
> An error occurred trying to connect: Get
> http://localhost:2375/v1.21/containers/json?all=1: dial tcp
> 127.0.0.1:2375: ConnectEx tcp: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

I was trying to correct the error using the instruction present in this forum -
https://forums.docker.com/t/windows-an-error-occurred-trying-to-connect/4384

I am facing an error in the last step i.e. running this command in git bash -

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('"C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe" env --shell cmd machinename') DO %i
```

The error which I get is

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Any help to solve this issue? I tried to escape the single and double quotes and that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am facing an error in the last step i.e. running this command in git
>   bash -
>
> ```
> FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('"C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe" env --shell cmd machinename') DO %i
> ```

This is `batch` syntax, in `bash` this should work:

```
eval `docker-machine env`
```